How to show the tooltip values in percentage
I have a time series panel in Grafana, and it’s stacked 100%, and I would like to know if it’s possible to display the values on the tooltip as percentage to.
So right now, my panel looks like

 SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(year, '-01-01'), '%Y-%m-%d') AS time, ROUND(quantity / 
 1000000, 2) as 'Europe (excl.EU-27)'
 FROM net4co2.ghg_world_emission_per_region
 WHERE data_type = 'CU' AND category = 'E'
 ORDER BY time;

The desired one


Doubt this is possible. And if you don't care about absolute values, why not query data source to get percentages?

@markalex I thought about query the data to create a percentage, but I don't have the total value, I would need to create a complex query, but I think I'm going to try that
